# Spring Boot causes SSL peer handshake failure with self-signed certs

Tags: java, macos, curl, spring-boot, keytool

I have created a [GitHub project that perfectly reproduces](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting) everything explained here.

---

I am building a Spring Boot app (with an embedded Jetty web container) and am trying to get it to serve self-signed OpenSSL certs when running locally (when running on staging or prod environments, the app will be serving a root CA-signed cert).

So to create the SSL capabilities, first I created the [public key/CSR](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/myapp-csr.pem) by issuing:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myapp-key.pem -out myapp-csr.pem -days 3650
```

Then I created the JKS and imported my public key like so:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file myapp-csr.pem -alias myorg -keystore myapp.jks
```

I then updated my [`application.yml`](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/application.yml#L8) with SSL properties:

```
ssl:
  key-store: 'myapp.jks'
  key-store-password: '123456'
  key-password: '123456'
```

I then run my Spring Boot app:

```
./gradlew build && java -Dspring.config=. -jar build/libs/spring-boot-troubleshooting.jar
```

So far so good -- no errors/exceptions/warnings at startup. I then open a new terminal and run:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://localhost:9200/health
curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

If I switch back over to the terminal where the app is running, I now see this in the console output:

```
06:14:00.149 [qtp1706099897-15] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@5b876b3[p=1,l=175,c=8192,r=174]={\x16<<<\x03\x01\x00\xAa\x01\x00\x00\xA6\x03\x03ZL\xBa\xF8T\x86r...\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00>>>-Type: applicatio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
```

The `-k` is to intentional **ignore SSL** since this is a self-signed cert. I've tried both with and without `-k` and the result is the same.

I see [evidence that this *could* be a MacOS issue for some reason](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1797), but frankly I'm not even sure where to start looking. Something wrong with the way I created the public/private key pair? Something wrong with the way I imported the public key/CSR into the JKS file? Something else wrong with any aspect of my configuration?

Comment: _"I have created a GitHub project..."_ Sorry, but the point of SO is to be a resource ***in the future***, long after your project is gone from GitHub.  This is why questions must be self-contained and should not rely on external resources.  Please include the code for your [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison - but I have! You have everything above to reproduce my exact issue, provided that you have a templated + functional Spring Boot web app on hand. I'm not going to paste in the ~10 boilerplate source code files required to run a Spring Boot application, which is why I went to the trouble of providing one on GitHub. Everything I have pasted in above will also be meaningful and useful to any viewers, long after my project is gone from GitHub. **If you still disagree with anything I'm saying here, please let me know what you think would constitute an MCVE/SSCCE in this case**.

Comment: Also, please reconsider your DV/CV, its a little harsh given all the information I've provided here. On SE CVs should be given if the question is off-topic. DVs should be given if you simply feel this is a bad question at heart. Personally I don't think either are the case, but you are of course free to disagree.

Comment: @smeeb There are multiple reasons for close-votes, and 'off-topic' is only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EJP explained root cause well. There is no private key in your myapp.jks file.

I can tell the solutions detailed. There are 3 solution. I tested them by your code and java 8.

1. only keytool - fastest one

   remove existing myapp.jks and regenerate by keytool with these parameters.

   > keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=Name Surname, ou=MyUnit, o=MyOrg, c=US" -alias myorg -keypass 123456 -storepass 123456 -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -keystore myapp.jks
2. only openssl

   Create pkcs file by openssl named "myapp.p12".

   > openssl pkcs12 -inkey myapp-key.pem -in myapp-csr.pem -export -out myapp.p12;

   change application.yml   key-store: 'myapp.jks' to   key-store: 'myapp.p12'
3. combination of them(current method).

   Create pkcs file by openssl named "myapp.p12".

   > openssl pkcs12 -inkey myapp-key.pem -in myapp-csr.pem -export -out myapp.p12;

   import it into jks file

   > keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myapp.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore myapp.jks -deststoretype JKS

Comment: Thank you @Mehmet (+1)!!! Fantastic answer and I ended up going with Option #1 (keytool-only) and it worked perfectly right out of the starting gate. Also thank you for being **polite**, **courteous** and **respectful** unlike some of the other denizens walking around these boards...

Answer (score 1):

To perform the SSL handshake server keystore must contain both public certificate and private key. The easiest way to do it is to create a `p12` bundle with private key and certificate and import both of them at once using `importkeystore` command.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myapp-key.pem -out myapp-csr.pem -days 3650 -subj '/CN=localhost'
openssl pkcs12 -export -in myapp-csr.pem -inkey myapp-key.pem -out keystore.p12
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass 123456 -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

Now you will be able to query your server using `curl`.

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://localhost:9200/health
curl --cacert myapp-csr.pem -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:9200/health
```

So basically your configuration is correct except for missing private key in keystore.

Answer (score -1):

None of this makes sense.

- You don't need to use `openssl` at all.
- A CSR is not a certificate, let alone a public key.
- The result of importing a CSR into a KeyStore is not a valid KeyStore, as there is no private key.

You need to use the `keytool`, and nothing else, as follows:

1. `keytool -genkey ...`
2. `keytool -selfcert ...`

   using the same alias both times.
3. `keytool -export ...`
4. `keytool -import ...` into the clients' *truststore* file(s).